# Share data between a directive and a controller in different modules

Tags: angularjs

I have been playing with AngularJS for just a few days and came up with something that I could not solve yet.

Each contact can have multiple addresses and phone numbers. Since inserting and editing a contact will require almost the same functionality at the UI level, I decided to create a directive like to following to deal with addresses and phones:

**Address:**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("AddressesEditorModule", []);
    app.directive("addressesEditor", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "/addressesEditorTemplate.html",
            controller: function ($scope) {
                this.addresses = [
                    // this will hold addresses.
                ];

                // ...
            }
        }
})();
```

**Phone:**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("PhonesEditorModule", []);
    app.directive("phonesEditor", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl: "/phonesEditorTemplate.html",
            controller: function ($scope) {
                this.phones = [
                    // this will hold phones.
                ];

                // ...
            }
        }
})();
```

I have omitted the methods declared inside the directives to work with the `addresses` and `phones` variables.

Both directives are used like this at the HTML:

```
<div ng-app="ContactModule">
    <div ng-controller="InsertController as insertCtrlr">
        <!-- some other elements handling contact name goes here -->

        <addresses-editor></addresses-editor>
        <phones-editor></phones-editor>
    </div>
</div>
```

This work exactly as I expected to, with phones and addresses being correctly recorded.

Now, what I want to do is to retrieve the phones and addresses inside the directive and send them to the server in order to be recorded at the contact at the database.

I know how to perform the AJAX, but I have no idea how to exchange data between the directives and the `InsertController` (the variables with the data I want are: `this.addresses` from `addressesEditor` directive and `this.phones` from `phonesEditor` directive).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a shared Service/Factory with the data you want to share.

To illustrate how it can be done, I created some example code using a service to share data between Controllers and Directives:

```
app.factory('SharedService', function() {
  return {
    sharedObject: {
      value: ''
    }
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1VdKJP2tpvqqJL1LF6m?p=preview

Hope that helps