# How can I take data from an external controller into a directive template?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a factory who provide data to a controller but when I call from the directive the data do not bind.

```
myApp.directive('user',function(){
    return{
        replace:true,
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
        },
        template:'<h1>User name: {{userName}}</h1>',
        link: function(scope,elem,attr){
        }   
    }
});

myApp.controller('MembriController', ['$scope', 'facebook',function($scope,facebook){
    facebook.membersData().then(function(response){
        //console.log(response);

        var obj = angular.fromJson(response);
        var nrMembri = obj.data.length;
        $scope.nrMembri=nrMembri;
        $scope.users=obj.data;
        for(var i=0; i<nrMembri; i++){
            var userName = obj.data[i].name;
            $scope.userName=userName;
        };
    });
}]); 

<div id="membri">
<h1>Hera are all of {{nrMembri}} members</h1>

<div ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:'name'">
    <user userName="userName"></user>
</div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/whAnVxy18NfhM4MtqVCl?p=catalogue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Share data between a directive and a controller in different modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25370582/share-data-between-a-directive-and-a-controller-in-different-modules)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you always share data between your controllers and directives using a Service/Factory and injecting it on both sides.

```
app.factory('SharedService', function() {
  return {
    sharedObject: {
      value: '',
      value2: ''
    }
  };
});

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, SharedService) {
  $scope.model = SharedService.sharedObject;
});

app.directive('myDirective',['SharedService', function(SharedService){
  return{
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope){
      scope.model = SharedService.sharedObject;
    },
    template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="model.value"/></div>'
  }
}]);
```

Here is a plunkr showing how it can be done:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Q1VdKJP2tpvqqJL1LF6m

Answer (score -1):

You could use $rootScope to pass along variable across your appliation.

[Documentation on rootScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)